# How to relay cin from main into fucntions and struct above main?

Tags: c++

ok so i need to figure out how to place the cin user entered in main into the function, and then from the function into the struct; im clueless on what i need to do in the main not just regarding the code but how it connects (memory wise) what is written into the main with the rest of the program. the #include must be ONLY iostream, vector ANDstring!

p.s  at the end i need to print out the films stored in the vector of films

```
using namespace std;



struct Film
{
    string Name;
    double Length;
    string Producer;
    string Lead_Role;
    string Type;
};

Film create_film()
{
    Film f;

    cout << "Enter the name of the movie: ";
    getline(cin, f.Name);

    cout << "Enter movie length: ";
    cin >> f.Length;
    cin.ignore;

    cout << "Enter the producer: : ";
    getline(cin, f.Producer);

    cout << "Enter the lead role: ";
    getline(cin, f.Lead_Role);

    cout << "Enter movie type";
    getline(cin, f.Type);

    return f;

}



int main()
{


//here i need to figure it out

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you calling your function from main?

Comment: Call `create_film()` in `main()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think (it's not completely clear) that you're just looking for

```
int main()
{
    Film my_film = create_film();
    // do something with my_film
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

The way I've used `create_file()` in main is called a *function call*. It's how you 'connect' one function to another, though 'transfer control' is probably a better way of saying it. When you call a function control transfers from the calling function (`main` in this case) to the called function (`create_film` in this case). When the called function returns control goes back to the calling function. And of course when the `main` function returns the program terminates.

Comment: ok so i didint type the last part of the task, my bad and sorry for it, at the end i need to print out the films stored in the vector of films

Comment: @Doppel OK, so update your question with the code you currently have for initialising and printing out the vector of films and I'll try and answer your new question. Or you could just post a whole new question.